# ASP.NET - Blazor - returning clicked generic type from templated component

Tags: asp.net, blazor

I'm learning Blazor and ASP.NET and have been learning C# for the last 6 months.

I have made a simple templated component:

```
@typeparam GenericType

<ul>
    @foreach (GenericType item in Items)
    { 
        <li @onclick="(x)=> ItemClicked(item)">FragmentToRender(item)</li>
    }    
</ul>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<GenericType> FragmentToRender { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public IReadOnlyList<GenericType> Items { get; set; }

    public void ItemClicked(GenericType item)
    {
         //To figure out...
    }
}
```

And I'm using it in a page component:

```
<TestComponent GenericType="Thing" Items="ListOfThings">
    <FragmentToRender>
        <p>@context.Field</p>
    </FragmentToRender>
</TestComponent>

@code
{
    private List<Thing> ListOfThings =
        new List<Thing> {
            new Thing("Test"),
            new Thing("Test2")
        };

    public class Thing
    {
        public readonly string Field;

        public Thing(string field) => Field = field;
    }    
}
```

When the OnClick event of the li element in the component is triggered, how can I pass the specific instance of the item back to the page component (i.e so a different component can do something with the clicked item like upload it's data somewhere)?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You should use an `EventCallback` to pass the data.

```
@typeparam GenericType

<ul>
    @foreach (GenericType item in Items)
    { 
        <li @onclick="(x)=> ItemClicked(item)">FragmentToRender(item)</li>
    }    
</ul>

@code {
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<GenericType> FragmentToRender { get; set; }

    [Parameter] public IReadOnlyList<GenericType> Items { get; set; }

    // Added EventCallback parameter
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<GenericType> OnClick { get; set; }

    public void ItemClicked(GenericType item)
    {
         // Checking if EventCallback is set
         if(OnClick.HasDelegate)
         {
             // Calling EventCallback
             OnClick.InvokeAsync(item);
         }
    }
}
```

And then just pass the parameter `OnClick` to that component to get the item

```
@* Passing the OnClick parameter *@
<TestComponent GenericType="Thing" Items="ListOfThings" OnClick="@HandleClick">
    <FragmentToRender>
        <p>@context.Field</p>
    </FragmentToRender>
</TestComponent>

@code
{

    private void HandleClick(Thing item)
    {
        // Do what you want with the item
    }

    private List<Thing> ListOfThings =
        new List<Thing> {
            new Thing("Test"),
            new Thing("Test2")
        };

    public class Thing
    {
        public readonly string Field;

        public Thing(string field) => Field = field;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: I've made some alteration in your code sample...
Point to note:

- Add a @ symbol before FragmentToRender(item). It instructs the compiler to treat FragmentToRender(item) as executable code. Otherwise, it is used as the content of the li element.
- In the second version of the li element, we place the the event call back in 
  the body of the lambda expression. If you use this version, comment out the
  ItemClicked method.

### TemplatedComponent.razor

```
 @typeparam GenericType

<ul>
    @foreach (GenericType item in Items)
    {
        <li @onclick="() => ItemClicked(item)">@FragmentToRender(item)</li>
        @*<li @onclick="@(() => SelectedItem.InvokeAsync(item))">@FragmentToRender(item)</li>*@
    }
</ul>

@code {
[Parameter] public RenderFragment<GenericType> FragmentToRender { get; set; }

[Parameter] public IReadOnlyList<GenericType> Items { get; set; }
// Define an event call back property.
[Parameter] public EventCallback<GenericType>  SelectedItem { get; set; }

public async Task ItemClicked(GenericType item)
{
    // Check if the event call back property contains a delegate. It's 
    // important to understand that the EventCallback type is not a true 
    // delegate. It is actually a struct that may contain a delegate 
    if(SelectedItem.HasDelegate)
    {
      await  SelectedItem.InvokeAsync(item);
    }

}
}
```

### TestComponent.razor

```
<TemplatedComponent GenericType="Thing" Items="ListOfThings" 
                                     SelectedItem="SelectedItem">
    <FragmentToRender>
        <p>@context.Field</p>
    </FragmentToRender>
</TemplatedComponent>


@code
{
 // Define a method that will be called by the event call back 'delegate'. It
 // receives a single parameter from the calling delegate.
private async Task SelectedItem(Thing item)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Field);
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
private List<Thing> ListOfThings =
    new List<Thing> {
        new Thing("Test"),
        new Thing("Test2")
        };

public class Thing
{
    public readonly string Field;

    public Thing(string field) => Field = field;
}
}
```

### Index.razor

```
 @page "/"

<TestComponent/>
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks!


I'm guessing EventCallback<T> is like using events and delegates in C# where the event type is a wrapper for the delegate.


In the second version of the <li> where it invokes the event callback directly is there a reason for that version that you don't need to check if there's anything assigned to it?

Comment: Also in the SelectedItem what's the benefit of using await Task.Complete? As far as I've read it runs the code after the await statement concurrently (returning from the function so that other code can continue) then when it completes it picks back up below the await statement running in a new thread?

Comment: No, there isn't really a reason for not checking if EventCallback type has a delegate. You may add such checking if you like. Actually, I use the checking in the ItemClicked method only for educational purposes. It is not critical... you can do without it, and you may notice, if you spend some time in github, that most code produced by the blazor team does not apply this checking.

Comment: "Also in the SelectedItem what's the benefit of using await Task.Complete?" No benefit at all. I could have written "private void SelectedItem(Thing item)" Again, this is done for educational purposes... The benefit is that you understand what is going on, and will not fail when you'll need to code like this. I use "await Task.CompletedTask" here because I want to use async Task...